# Значения из edit

Tags: delphi

Перевожу текст в верхний регистр после символов, что указаны в Edit1.Text и Edit2.Text.

В этом примере беру значения из Edit1.Text и Edit2.Text (в едитах указаны символы ;:)

```
s := Copy(s,1,(Pos(Edit1.Text,s) or Pos(Edit2.Text,s))) + AnsiUpperCase(Copy(s,(Pos(Edit1.Text,s) or Pos(Edit2.Text,s))+1));
```

Как брать значения из одного Edit1.Text в цикле? (Делаю вот так, но не работает):

```
for z := 0 to Length(Edit1.text) do
begin
  s := Copy(s,1,(Pos(Edit1.text[z],s) )) + AnsiUpperCase(Copy(s,(Pos(Edit1.text[z],s))+1));
end;
```

Comment: Ваши `Edit1.text` и т.п. только загромождают текст. Работа со строками? Вот и прочитайте текст из контролов в строки с понятными именами переменных, и работайте с ними. Что, по-вашему, делает (Pos(...) **or** Pos(...) ? C какого индекса нумеруются символы строк (for z,...)?

Comment: @MBo, а чем же Edit1.text загромождает текст ? А в (Pos(...) or Pos(...)  я прописывал разделители.

Comment: @MaksimGurov, `Edit1.text` часто повторяется, поэтому имеет смысл его значение в переменную положить (например, `text`) и уже эту переменную использовать

Comment: @gil9red, а как это сделать ? Подскажите?

Comment: Что делает оператор `or` в указанном случае?

Comment: @MBo, Оператор or  - указывает на выбор вариантов. То есть символа (разделителя), указанного в Edit1 или Edit2.

Comment: Логичнее тогда уж было бы: `Copy(s, 1, Pos(Edit1.Text or Edit2.Text, s))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MaksimGurov,** Если я Вас правильно поняла, то вам нужно: после указанных символов (что в **Edit1**) - в строках, перевести весь текст в верхний регистр ?.

**Если да,** то тогда этот вопрос можно решить очень просто: Сначала нужно объявить переменные:

**Обновила ответ (ПОЛНОСТЬЮ ГОТОВЫЙ КОД - №3):**

```
   // Функция приводит к единому разделителю " Символу - : "
 function Rpl(const aString: string): string;
begin
 // Делаем замену
  Result := StringReplace(aString,';',':',[]);
  Result := StringReplace(Result,'+',':',[]);
 // И так далее....
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
TStrin:TStringList;
i:Integer;
str:string;
begin
TStrin :=TStringList.Create;
// Загружаем файл
TStrin.LoadFromFile('test.txt');
//На всякий случай проверяем Edit на пустоту
if Edit1.Text='' then ShowMessage('Укажите разделители?!')
else begin
Edit1.Text :=Trim(Edit1.Text);
// Проходим циклом
for i := 0 to TStrin.Count-1 do
  begin
  //Вот это заменяем на преобразованную строку в исходном файле
  str:=TStrin[i];
  // Вот тут подключаем функцию Rpl
   str := Rpl (str);
  // Перевод строки после указанных знаков в верхний регистр
  str := Copy(str, 1,(Pos(':', str))) + AnsiUpperCase(Copy(str,(Pos(':', str))+1));
 //Вот это заменяем на преобразованную строку в исходном файле
  TStrin[i] :=str;
  end;
  // Сохраняем результат
TStrin.SaveToFile('Sav_Rez.txt');
 // Освобождаем TStringList
FreeAndNil(TStrin);
end;
end;
```

Comment: @MaksimGurov и Татьяна, вы оба понимаете, что делает этот код? `(Pos(rEd1, str) or Pos(rEd2, str))`

Comment: @MaksimGurov и Татьяна. `or` стоящий между двумя целыми выполняет битовую операцию, то есть возвращает целое, каждый бит которого - это результат логического "ИЛИ" соответствующих битов операндов. Например, `(1 or 2)` получится `3`.

Comment: `rEd1` и `rEd2` надо проверять по отдельности.

Comment: Он работает, потому что только один из символов `rEd1`/`rEd2` встречается в проверяемых строках. То есть один из операндов всегда ноль. Тогда результат побитового `OR` равен втором операнду.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что значит "перевести все разделители к единому". Надо выяснить у автора вопроса, что он хочет делать, когда в строке есть оба разделителя.

Comment: @Татьяна, Да, если это возможно. Конечно да.

Comment: @Igor, Переделала код для MaksimGurov. Что скажете своим опытным взглядом. Так лучше или ?

Comment: @Татьяна, Вот последний вариант очень шикарен. Ну хотя бы потому что я могу свести все разделители к единому. Сегодня на меня было потрачено много времени. За что Вам спасибо!

Comment: кхм, кхм. Татьяна, Вы молодец, что не сдаетесь ). Если Вы заменили все потенциальные разделители на двоеточия, то почему Вы продолжаете искать в строке `rEd1`?

Comment: @Igor, Исправила в Pos прописала двоеточие, то я уже по инерции, голова забита. Вот так думаю правильней.?

Comment: Я не думаю, что это то, что нужно автору вопроса, но он почему-то не хочет подробно, с примерами ввода и вывода, объяснить, чего пытается добиться.

Comment: @Igor, Уже именно то. У меня в  строках 3 разделителя и мне нужно было все после них перевести в верхний регистр. Вопрос решен и разжеван на 100%. Igor, Татьяна спасибо Вам за потраченное на меня - время!

Comment: @MaksimGurov, Ну если все хорошо то рада была помочь. Всем добра и приятного рабочего дня :).